# NestJS axios interceptor

Tags: typescript, http, axios, nestjs, interceptor

I'm working on a project in NestJS where I need to communicate with an external API. I've created an Axios interceptor to handle authentication. So far, this has been working on a simple POST endpoint where I sent JSON body, even when the bearer token needed refreshing or was accessible.

However, now I need to attach a file with a POST request. This request works in Postman, just as I've implemented it in the service. However, if the bearer token is not accessible/needs refreshing, unfortunately, this request doesn't return anything. In fact, in Postman, it keeps spinning indefinitely.

If I cancel the previous call in Postman (meaning the bearer was refreshed but the request got stuck), the next call correctly performs the POST request and sends back the response.

So, when there's no need to refresh the bearer token and the existing token is used, it works. However, when a refresh is required, it doesn't return anything and just keeps spinning indefinitely.

Do you have any ideas about what the issue might be?

Interceptor code:

```
import { CallHandler, ExecutionContext, Injectable, Logger, NestInterceptor } from "@nestjs/common";
import { HttpService } from "@nestjs/axios";
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, HttpStatusCode } from "axios";
import { DummyService } from "./Dummy.service";
import { ConfigService } from "@nestjs/config";
import { Observable, firstValueFrom } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class DummyInterceptor
{
  private readonly logger = new Logger(DummyInterceptor.name);
  DummyApiBearerToken: string;

  constructor(private httpService: HttpService, private DummyService: DummyService, private configService: ConfigService) 
  {

    this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.request.use( (config) =>
    {
      console.log("Axios request interceptor");
      if(config.url.startsWith(this.configService.get("Dummy_API_URL")))
      {
        config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + this.DummyApiBearerToken;
        config.headers["Accept"] = "application/json";
        console.log(config.headers);
      }
      
      return config;
    });

    this.httpService.axiosRef.interceptors.response.use( (response) =>
    {
      console.log("Axios response interceptor");
      console.log(response.data);
     return response; 
    }, async (error) =>
    {
      this.logger.log("Dummy API error interceptor");
      this.logger.error(error.response.data)
      const originalRequest = error.config;
      if (error.response.status === HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized && !originalRequest._retry) 
      {
        this.logger.log("Unauth, refreshing Dummy bearer");
        originalRequest._retry = true;

        const response = await this.DummyService.getNewBearerToken();
        this.DummyApiBearerToken = response.data["access_token"];

        return this.httpService.axiosRef(originalRequest);   
      }

      return Promise.reject(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Service code:

```
import { Injectable, Logger } from '@nestjs/common';
import { ConfigService } from '@nestjs/config';
import axios, { AxiosInstance } from 'axios';
import { ReplaySubject, firstValueFrom, from} from 'rxjs';
import FormData = require("form-data")
import { HttpService } from '@nestjs/axios';
import * as fs from 'fs';



@Injectable()
export class DummyService 
{
    private readonly logger = new Logger(DummyService.name);

    private readonly refreshDummyTokenAxios: AxiosInstance;


    constructor(private readonly http: HttpService, private configService: ConfigService)
    {
        this.refreshDummyTokenAxios = axios.create();

    }
    
    getNewBearerToken()
    {
        console.log("Sending request to get new bearer token");
        const headers = { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" };
        const params = {
            "client_id": this.configService.get("Dummy_API_CLIENT_ID"),
            "client_secret": this.configService.get("Dummy_API_CLIENT_SECRET"),
            "scope": this.configService.get("Dummy_API_SCOPE"),
            "grant_type": "client_credentials"
        };

        return this.refreshDummyTokenAxios.post(this.configService.get("Dummy_API_TOKEN_URL"), params, {headers: headers});
    }

    async uploadAttachmentToDummyEntry(DummyEntryId: number, attachmentFilepath: string)
    {
         this.logger.log("Uploading attachment to Dummy Entry started...")
 
         let uploadAttachmentFormData = new FormData();
         uploadAttachmentFormData.append("attachment[file]", fs.createReadStream(attachmentFilepath))
 
         const config =
         {
             maxBodyLength: 100 * 1024 * 1024, // 100 MB in bytes,
             maxContentLength: 100 * 1024 * 1024, // 100 MB in bytes,
             headers: {
                 "Accept": "application/json",
                 "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data",
             }
         }
 
         const asd = await firstValueFrom(this.http.post(this.configService.get("Dummy_API_URL") + `/invoices/${DummyEntryId}/attachments`, uploadAttachmentFormData, config))
         .catch((error) =>
         {
             console.log(error);
             return error;
         });
 
         return asd;
    }

}
```

Debug controller:

```
  @Get()
  async getHello()
  {
    try {
      const response = await this.dummyService.uploadAttachmentToDummyEntry(
        763402,
        "C:\\Users\\username\\Documents\\dummy.pdf"
      );
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error in getHello:", error);
      throw error; 
    }
  }
```